# How to access to a docker container via SSH using IP address?

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-container, ipv4, nvidia-docker

I'm using NVIDIA Docker in a Linux machine (Ubuntu 20.04). I've created a container named `user1` using `nvidia/cuda:11.0-base` image as follows:

```
docker run --gpus all --name user1 -dit nvidia/cuda:11.0-base /bin/bash
```

And, here is what I see if I run `docker ps -a`:

```sh
admin@my_desktop:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
a365362840de   nvidia/cuda:11.0-base                  "/bin/bash"              3 seconds ago    Up 2 seconds                         user1
```

I want to access to that container via `ssh` using its unique IP address from a totally different machine (other than `my_desktop`, which is the host). First of all, is it possible to grant each container a unique IP address? If so, how can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A container is usually a wrapper around a single process. What you want sounds more like a full VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to access to your container with ssh from an external VM, you need to do the following

1. Install the ssh daemon for your container
2. Run the container and expose its ssh port

I would propose the following Dockerfile, which builds from `nvidia/cuda:11.0-base` and creates an image with the ssh daemon inside

**Dockerfile**

```
# Instruction for Dockerfile to create a new image on top of the base image (nvidia/cuda:11.0-base)
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.0-base
ARG root_password
RUN apt-get update || echo "OK" && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo "root:${root_password}" | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -i 's/#PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Build the image from the Dockerfile

```
docker image build --build-arg root_password=password --tag nvidia/cuda:11.0-base-ssh .
```

Create the container

```
docker container run -d -P --name ssh nvidia/cuda:11.0-base-ssh
```

Run `docker ps` to see the `container port`

[image]

Finally, access the container

```
ssh -p 49157 root@<VM_IP>
```

---

**EDIT**: As David Maze correctly pointed out. You should be aware that the root password will be visible in the `image history`. Also this way overwrites the original container process.

This process, if it is to be adopted it needs to be modified in case you need it for production use. This serves as a starting point for someone who wishes to add ssh to his container.

Comment: (Remember that the ssh daemon will run _instead of_ the normal container process.  I believe the root password will also be visible in plain text in the `docker inspect` output, and every time you rebuild the image it will have a different ssh host key.)

Comment: @DavidMaze you are correct, added your pointers to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @TolisGerodimos Thanks for your answer. I followed the steps you've written above, and successfully created the container using the Dockerfile provided. But I don't get how I can access the container using `ssh -p 49157 root@<VM_IP>`. What do you mean by `<VM_IP>`, and what operations should be done on my VM to enable this?

Comment: The <VM_IP> is a placeholder for the ip address from which you access your Linux machine externally

Comment: @TolisGerodimos Oh I see. The solution works. Thanks a lot for saving me a lot of time :)